# Continuous Google Chrome crashing on macOS Catalina

Tags: google-chrome, mac, crash, macos-catalina

Starting shortly after an OS update about 2 months ago, Google Chrome (my default browser) began crashing on my MacBook Air (2017) about once every 15-45 minutes during regular use. Aside from being generally infuriating, the crashes seem particularly difficult to fix. As for application conditions that lead to the crashing, there seems to be no obvious connection between what Chrome is doing and when the crashes occur. Chrome is also experiencing frequent crashing of individual tabs.

Here is what I've tried so far:

1. Disabling potentially problematic extensions (no effect)
2. Uninstalling and reinstalling Chrome (along with clearing all associated files from the library) (no effect)
3. Looking at the crash dump from the OS side, I found an exception that referenced too many files being open. Checking online, I found that others experienced this problem on macOS and tried to remedy it by modifying the upper limits allowed for the OS and for specific processes. Even pushing the limits almost twice as high as default had no impact. (no effect)

I have included the full crash report generated by macOS, but I don't expect anyone to comb through it in full. At this point I'm not looking for a magical solution, just some guidance on where to go from here in the diagnostic process. I have my Chrome crash dumps as well, but am not sure how to read them.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UyjkFcbmV10mWCY4mB5cHljTB7hhbKIs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I seem to be having exactly the same issue.